# In asynchronous communication how is the frequency same but clocks of both devices different?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, digital-communications, 8051

Am currently studying 8051 microcontroller and in the course the lecturer told that in communication the frequencies of sender and receiver should be same else they will get different bits of data at different speeds and that would result in either data loss or extra useless data.

In synchronous communication both clock and frequency is same and in asynchronous communication clocks are different.

But as per my understanding the frequency generates the clock , then how are they both different?

Comment: Async uses 16x clock to sync on 1st edge

Comment: Although there are purely asynchronous systems in theory, almost all systems are fundamental synchronous, it is just that two communicating systems that are each based on a local clock do not have their clocks synchronized even if they might be at the same frequency. They communicate asynchronously by each using synchronous digital logic.

Comment: Google UART. How it works. The 16x sampling like Tony said. The two devices can communicate as long as their internal idea of frequency is not too far off from each other and time is allocated to resynchronize at the end of each byte so timing errors don't accumulate.

Comment: Just FYI. I've used devices that employed 64X (and also 4X) over-sampling to perform the same job that is preformed by devices using 16X. So, don't buy the idea of only 16X. (These were standard IC devices and not me using bit-bang.)

Comment: Also to the OP. Even if the frequencies of the two MCUs are nominally the same, where they are driven by separate clock sources with the same nameplate frequency, they won't be the same and they will drift around relative to each other. So they are only the same if both driven by the same clock source.

Comment: synchronous Rx uses a VCO or phase shifting clock by counter divider controlled by phase error in mixer to achieve sync in both frequency and phase, but UART’s only need to be <10% error at f using 16x clk to be Ok for each 10 to 12 bit byte including start bit.

Comment: In a microprocessor, the clock is derived from (usually)  a crystal oscillator on the same circuit board as the microprocessor. If you randomly select two crystals, their frequencies will be close but not exactly the same. In order to do asynchronous communications between processors, various tricks have to be used. Even though it is a challenging problem to solve, various solutions have been implemented decades ago and now they are taken for granted. The UART is one solution.

Answer (score 1):

In synchronous communication, one clock source is used for both transmitter and receiver, with designed propagation times so that transmitter and receiver phases are always correctly aligned.

In asynchronous communication, two independent clock sources of the same nominal frequency are used. The only requirement is that the frequencies be within a tolerance of each other, not that they are identical. For any one word, the phase will be relatively consistent, but it may change between words. It is up to the receiver to handle the changing phase shift, usually by over-sampling and deciding for each word where to put the sampling instant.

Comment: Even source synchronous links (such as PCIe and Infiniband) can have local oscillators that are within a nominal tolerance (although they do require other measures such as FIFOs and specialised link control such as the skip ordered set).

Comment: @PeterSmith   not sure what inifiniband is physically (wikipedia not clear), but then how do you go on to classify 'embedded' source clocks as in HDMI and SATA? The receive PLL obviously has to be close to the right frequency, but is actively locked the way that async UARTS are not. Given the apparent state of knowledge of the OP, I think my answer went far enough.

Comment: It was an observation not a correction and your answer does indeed go far enough but it serves to show that there are some very grey areas in communication links. Infiniband is, in many ways, the fore-runner to PCI express (the state machines are very similar) although it is a fabric (peers only) - I did a lot of it in the early 2000s (I was part of a lot of the working groups at the time).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, we're referring to low-level physical connections.

With synchronous communication, both sender and receiver share the same clock. Example would be SPI, which relies on a common clock.

Asynchronous communication doesn't require a common clock. Instead, it relies on the receiver recovering clock (and framing) from the signal being sent down the wire. Example would be UART, where the transmitter sends a start bit to align the receiver's clock and frame the data that follows.

How does this work when the UART link partners have different timebases? The UART receiver reference clock is generated at a higher frequency (commonly 16x baud rate). The 1x rate baud clock is based on this local 16x one. The 1x clock is re-aligned to the middle of a bit-time using the start bit as a trigger. Since this happens every frame (byte), any clock drift that may happen during the reception of a frame is effectively covered over. In short, the start bit establishes the frame boundary and bit timing for the rest of the frame.

Nevertheless, for a UART link to work there has to be *some* agreement at both ends (within a few percent) on the data baud rate.

A variant of UART uses a separate clock: USART. The 'S' in USART means synchronous. But it goes beyond that: USARTs support more protocols at higher bit rates than UARTs. The two of the best-known USART-based protocol are probably IBM's SDLC and its descendant HDLC, which were widely used to connect terminals to mainframes.

More about UARTs vs. USARTs here: https://www.edn.com/usart-vs-uart-know-the-difference/

More about SDLC and its cousins here: https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/SDLC

Ethernet and other 802.x protocols have rendered SDLC/HDLC and the like obsolete.

Some consider SPI a USART interface, but I think that is misleading. SPI most often uses third signal, chip select, to initiate the beginning of a transfer. In contrast USART protocols like SDLC use in-band means to identify transfers, such as inter-packet idle periods.

Things get a bit murky when discussing source-synchronous interfaces. For example, MIPI CSI-2 has two different link schemes:

- DPHY: data with separate clock
- CPHY: clock embedded with data

CPHY receivers recover the bit clock from the channel, while DPHY receivers use the separate clock to sample the data. Yet, they both do the same thing (CPHY a bit more efficiently).

Is CPHY asynchronous, while DPHY is synchronous? I think it's the wrong question to ask. The question is, is the protocol self-clocking? And, how are data frames determined?

Answer (score 0):

The clocks are slightly different at each end, and even if they start perfectly synchronized, they will slowly drift out of phase with each other, but they aren't *completely* independent. Every time the transmitting device changes its TX line level, this can be used by the receiver as a indicator of the transmitter's clock state, and enables the receiver to re-synchronise its own clock with the transmitter.

Every time the receiver notices a transition from low to high (or high to low) during a frame, it can reset its internal "time counter" to zero, so that it knows how long to wait before it can expect the next bit to arrive.

It's possible for the transmitter to send a long string of consecutive ones or zeros, in which there is an absence of such transitions. To avoid this condition, each data frame contains start and stop bits, to guarantee that at least one such transition occurs per frame.

In this manner, the two clocks keep themselves in sync, but that doesn't mean they can have very different frequencies. They still must have roughly the same frequency, similar enough to remain sufficiently synchronized during an entire transmitted frame that contains *no* transitions, with which the receiver may re-align its own clock.

Answer (score 0):

> ...my understanding the frequency generates the clock...

The "clock frequency" for the transmission is generated by the crystal oscillator and various multipliers and dividers, as is necessary, by the sending device.

The "clock frequency" for the reception is generated by the crystal oscillator and various multipliers and dividers, as is necessary, by the receiving device.

The sender and receiver must agree, prior to engaging in communication, what the bit rate will be.

> ...then how are they both different?

All else being equal, the crystal oscillators cannot be the same frequency exactly, so the sender and reciever frequencies will drift over time relative to each other.